# comparing input with a file and minding the sequence

Tags: python, linux, command-line-arguments

How can I compare the values of input parmeters with a file in such a way that the sequence of the lines in file are "respected". For example:

file sequence.txt has following enteries

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

and the input is coming like this (with comas):

```
./run.py -c migrate -s ddd,bbb
```

then output is like this:

```
bbb
ddd
```

Here is the script I have worked so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import getopt
import time
import os

def main(argv):
    cmd = ''
    schemas = ''

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    seq_file = "system/sequence.txt"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, seq_file)

    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"h:c:s",["cmd=","schemas="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
       print './run.py -c=<command> -s=<schemas> '
       sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt == '-h':
           print './run.py -c=<command> -s=<schemas>'
           sys.exit()
       elif opt in ("-c", "--cmd"):
           cmd = arg
       elif opt in ("-s", "--schemas"):
           schemas = arg
    if cmd == "migrate" :
       with open(abs_file_path) as z: 
           for line in z:
             print line.rstrip('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I know that I have to do comparisons at position `print line.rstrip('\n')` but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Also, how can I make -s switch mandatory if -c has "migrate" value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module and in this case [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: Thanks Ilja for the recommendations. I didn't know about these as I am fairly new with python, and got 2 more days to do this and push for testing. Guess I am going to burn the midnight oil on these two:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the current line of the sequence is specified with the `-s` flag. So you need to modify the `schemas` value, so that it is a list that contains all schemas and then you can check if the current line is equal to one of the schemas. As for your second question, I'm not familiar with `getopt`, but you could simply check whether schemas is not empty when `-c` is `migrate` and do the approriate error handling.

```
[...]
schemas = []
[...]
    elif opt in ("-s", "--schemas"):
        schemas = arg.split(',')
[...]
if cmd == 'migrate':
    if not schemas:  # list is empty
        # do error handling
    for line in z:
        if line in schemas:
            print line
```